# MySQL combining two queries together

Tags: mysql

this my first question and I'm still learning Mysql so the problem I have is to combine two queries together

1st query :

```
SELECT
     stocks.Stock_Trans_No
     stocks.Stock_Date_Time,
     stocks.Stock_Trans_Type,
     stocks.Stock_Trans_Ref_No,
     stocks.Stock_Trans_Item_Code,
     stocks.Stock_Trans_Qty,
     stocks.Item_Description

FROM stocks

WHERE

DATE_FORMAT( stocks.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN   DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-01', '%Y%m%d') AND   DATE_FORMAT('2015-11-01', '%Y%m%d')  GROUP BY   stocks.`Stock_Trans_Item_Code`
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT 
SUM( stocks.Stock_Trans_Qty) 
FROM  stocks
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT( stocks.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') > '2015-09-01' 
GROUP BY stocks.`Stock_Trans_Item_Code`
```

how do I get these together. I'm still Studying so, please be kind enough to be as simple as you can! thank you

Comment: First of all describe what do you mean by `combine`?

Comment: Show us your desired output please.

Comment: First of all: it is queries not quarries (from query, not quarry, which is a whole different thing).

I assume you would like to achieve the result of both queries in a single one.

While reducing the number of queries is generally considered to be a good thing, it is not working here, because you have different (and for some results mutually exluding) conditions in your queries.

Comment: I meant in a one result or output
I'm sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT
SUM( IF(DATE_FORMAT( stocks.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') > '2015-09-01',stocks.Stock_Trans_Qty,0)) AS Stock_Trans_Qty_Sum
 stocks.Stock_Trans_No
 stocks.Stock_Date_Time,
 stocks.Stock_Trans_Type,
 stocks.Stock_Trans_Ref_No,
 stocks.Stock_Trans_Item_Code,
 stocks.Stock_Trans_Qty,
 stocks.Item_Description
FROM stocks
WHERE
DATE_FORMAT( stocks.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN   DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-01', '%Y%m%d') AND   DATE_FORMAT('2015-11-01', '%Y%m%d')  GROUP BY   stocks.`Stock_Trans_Item_Code`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT s1.*,
(SELECT SUM(s2.Stock_Trans_Qty)
 FROM stocks as s2
 WHERE
  s2.Stock_Trans_Item_Code = s1.Stock_Trans_Item_Code AND
  DATE_FORMAT(s2.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') > '2015-09-01'
 ) Total
FROM stocks as s1
WHERE
 DATE_FORMAT(s1.Stock_Date_Time, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-01', '%Y%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2016-11-01', '%Y%m%d')
GROUP BY s1.`Stock_Trans_Item_Code`
```